# JSTL: Passing a param into a Nested Include

Tags: jsp, variables, include, jstl, parameter-passing

Through the following code, I am able to pass a variable into an include:

```
<jsp:include page="navigation.jsp">
     <jsp:param name="page" value="product"/>   
</jsp:include>
```

BUT, how do I pass that same variable that I set in the root page, through the child include, and into another include?

```
<jsp:include page="breadcrumb.jsp">
     <jsp:param name="page" value="${param.page}"/> 
</jsp:include>
```

Comment: Looks to me like you answered your own question.   What you have shown should work.

Comment: well then... I guess I know more than I thought I did.

Answer (score 0):

include jsp is run before jstl ,so you can use ${param.page} in the include page not need through the include parameter way.